# Replace font awesome icon with an svg

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, font-awesome

I want to replace a font-awesome icon with and svg.

For example, if the css class is `class="'fa fa-square'"`, how can it be changed in order to use an svg file with the same shape, `square.svg`?

Answer (score 1):

All the font-awesome svg's are located in this handy github repo
[Font Awesome SVG's](https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/tree/master/black/svg)

You can insert the svg into a span, like so: *note you need to change the inline height and width, but leave the viewbox as is. To change the color of an svg, use fill: #colorvalue

```
<span>
    <svg width="1792" height="1792" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1664 416v960q0 119-84.5 203.5t-203.5 84.5h-960q-119 0-203.5-84.5t-84.5-203.5v-960q0-119 84.5-203.5t203.5-84.5h960q119 0 203.5 84.5t84.5 203.5z"/></svg>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same desire, and found my way with [Icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/app):

You can (for free) generate a font including only the icons you selected, with a nice GUI:

[image: In picture: Icomoon - GUI]

The CSS and HTML are also provided:

[image: In picture: Icomoon - GUI 2]

Only drawback, the free tier does not include WOFF2 file (but you get .eot, svg, ttf and woff - you may find a woff2 generator online)

**You prefer SVG?** No problem, it's also provided!

[image: In picture: Icomoon - generate SVG]